# Drupal db_select join 3 fields

Tags: 7, nodes, database

I want join to my select three fc fields:

- field_data_field_show_block_carousel
- field_data_field_poster_film
- field_data_field_film_link

I try this:

```
$nids = db_select('node', 'n');
  $nids->join(array('field_data_field_show_block_carousel', 'field_data_field_poster_film', 'field_data_field_film_link',), 'fc', 'n.nid = fc.entity_id');
  $nids->fields('fc', array('field_poster_film_fid','field_film_link_url',));
  $nids->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'uid',))
    ->condition('n.type', 'vodeo_library')
    ->condition('fc.field_show_block_carousel_value', 1)
    ->execute(); // returns an indexed array
  $result = $nids->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('nid');
```

but recived sql error? pls tell me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to write each join on a new line, not as an array. See [Joins](https://www.drupal.org/node/1848348) and [public function SelectQuery::join](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3Ajoin/7).

So try it like this:

```
$nids = db_select('node', 'n');
  $nids->join('field_data_field_show_block_carousel', 'fc', 'n.nid = fc.entity_id');
  $nids->join('field_data_field_poster_film', 'fp', 'n.nid = fp.entity_id');
  $nids->join('field_data_field_film_link', 'fl', 'n.nid = fl.entity_id');
  $nids->fields('fp', array('field_poster_film_fid'));
  $nids->fields('fl', array('field_film_link_url'));
  $nids->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'uid',))
    ->condition('n.type', 'vodeo_library')
    ->condition('fc.field_show_block_carousel_value', 1)
    ->execute(); // returns an indexed array
  $result = $nids->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('nid');
```

Depending on what your module attempts to achieve, you might also want to have a look at the default Drupal functions for attaching fields to nodes (you only have a condition on one field):

- [field_attach_load()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7)
- [field_get_items()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_get_items/7)
- [field_view_value()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7)

You can get a rendered field value like this:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$poster= field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_data_field_poster_film');
$output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field_data_field_poster_film', $poster[0]);
```

And if you don't mind a little overhead, you might want to try an [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708). It will give you all fields and is a little slower then a regular SQL query, but is much easier to read and change.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'vodeo_library')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->fieldCondition('field_show_block_carousel_value', 'value', 1, '=');

$result = $query->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $news_items_nids = array_keys($result['node']);
  $news_items = entity_load('node', $news_items_nids);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following query.

Note: Change table alias in $nids->fields('fc', array('field_poster_film_fid','field_film_link_url')); accordingly.

```
$nids = db_select('node', 'n');
$nids->join('field_data_field_show_block_carousel', 'fc', 'fc.entity_id = n.nid');
$nids->join('field_data_field_poster_film', 'ff', 'ff.entity_id = n.nid');
$nids->join('field_data_field_film_link', 'fl', 'fl.entity_id = n.nid');
$nids->fields('fc', array('field_poster_film_fid','field_film_link_url'));
$nids->fields('n', array('nid', 'title', 'uid'))
    ->condition('n.type', 'vodeo_library')
    ->condition('fc.field_show_block_carousel_value', 1, '=')
    ->execute(); // returns an indexed array
$result = $nids->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('nid');
```